# Can i flag SPECIFIC areas of a Tilemap in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D top down racing game in Unity
I have made 18 tracks, all with tilemaps and colliders attached to those tilemaps.

I am trying to introduce a new system, let me explain.
I have 4 different FULL tiles: Road, Trackside Grass, Grass, Water.
I also have many tiles that are e.g. half road half trackside grass to make certain areas smooth

I can't separate tilemaps because of the half/half tiles.

How can i try to flag certain areas? Or am i gonna have to spend months redesigning all the systems?

I don't want to redesign the system. I tried the tilemap separation on 1 of the tracks and the problem with half/half tiles happened. Please try to help me, i would be very gratefull

i hope someone helps me its been a while